# Wildcards in camel route

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have rest controller with request mapping as follows:

@PostMapping(value = "fpl/generate/{legIdentifier:.+}"

My camel route is defined as from("direct:/fpl/generate/").

The controller calls web service, web service calls FluentEndpointInvoker class which calls route defined above.

```
public class FluentEndpointInvoker {

@EndpointInject(uri = BASE_ENDPOINT_URI)
private FluentProducerTemplate producer;

@Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
private String contextRoot;

public <T, R> T request(Class<T> type, R request, HttpHeaders headers) {

    return producer.withProcessor(exchange -> {
        exchange.getIn().setBody(request, request.getClass());
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> exchange.getIn().setHeader(key, value));
        String endpoint = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
                .getRequestURI();
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(ROUTE_ENDPOINT_HEADER, "direct:".concat(endpoint.replaceFirst(contextRoot, "")));
    }).request(type);

}
```

}

The endpoint that is generated is something like direct:///fpl/generate/LH.1234.30Jun2016.FRA.BOG.X1. How can I configured wildcards in camel route so that endpoint can get called

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are not forced to use an endpoint with the full URI, you could simplify the case.

Instead of creating a dynamic endpoint, you could send all messages to the endpoint `direct:///fpl/generate` and set the full request URI as header on the message.

That way you have a simple route endpoint to use and the URI header to make decisions etc based on the full URI.